# Is an attorney who hasn't agreed to represent me yet required to keep our discussions confidential?

Tags: employment, attorney-client-privilege

I'm looking for an employment attorney and most seem to want the discuss the case, to see whether or not I have a case, before agreeing to represent me. Does this mean that any information I give them should remain confidential?

One of them has asked me to email him copies of emails I have that would be evidence in the case. Would he be required to keep them confidential?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

There is a special attorney-client confidentiality rule (at least in most U.S. jurisdictions) that requires an attorney to keep confidential and protects with the attorney-client privilege, information disclosed when an attorney and client are in the process of evaluating whether they want to establish an attorney-client relationship.

If enough relevant information is exchanged, this information can also create a conflict of interest that would prevent the attorney from representing the opposing party in the same dispute.

The ethical rule in states that have adopted a version of the Model Rules of Professional Conduct is Rule 1.18:

> Duties to Prospective Client
>
> (a)   A person who consults with a lawyer about the possibility of
>   forming a client-lawyer relationship with respect to a matter is a
>   prospective client.
>
> (b)   Even when no client-lawyer relationship ensues, a lawyer who has
>   learned information from a prospective client shall not use or reveal
>   that information, except as Rule 1.9 would permit with respect to
>   information of a former client.
>
> (c)   A lawyer subject to paragraph (b) shall not represent a client
>   with interests materially adverse to those of a prospective client in
>   the same or a substantially related matter if the lawyer received
>   information from the prospective client that could be significantly
>   harmful to the prospective client, except as provided in paragraph
>   (d). If a lawyer is disqualified from representation under this
>   paragraph, no lawyer in a firm with which that lawyer is associated
>   may knowingly undertake or continue representation in such a matter,
>   except as provided in paragraph (d).
>
> (d)   When the lawyer has received disqualifying information as defined
>   in paragraph (c), representation is permissible if:
>
> (1)   both the affected client and the prospective client have given
>   informed consent, confirmed in writing; or
>
> (2)   the lawyer who received the information took reasonable measures
>   to avoid exposure to more disqualifying information than was
>   reasonably necessary to determine whether to represent the prospective
>   client; and
>
> (i)   the disqualified lawyer is timely screened from any participation
>   in the matter and is apportioned no part of the fee therefrom; and
>
> (ii)  written notice is promptly given to the prospective client.